# 2 sided winform Tree - exist?

Tags: winforms, treeview

I'm looking for a 2 sided winform Tree control. something like what you see in the math books. meaning that the tree can go both right and left in the control.

Something like http://www.math.bas.bg/~nkirov/2010/NETB201/slides/ch06/pic3.jpg

Thanks

Avi

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly create a control for yourself deriving from the treeview and doing all the styling in the derived control. But I am sure it will be tedious thing. If you need to just show some data, in that case you can think of using SVG (its an XML inside) so that you can change data as you wish. Otherwise, think of WPF.

Comment: Nothing prepared? even for purchase?

Comment: I have not seen any out of the shelf so far for this.